# PRIMEFACES: empty p:dataTable (binding problem)

Tags: jsf, richfaces, primefaces

I've simply changed working JSF h:dataTable to p:dataTable, but it's empty. Without headers, one empty row. I've installed primefaces-3.0.M1.jar to my project.

[image]

**UPDATE**: if I remove **binding**, dataTable is working properly, but without advantages of HtmlDataTable...

**UPDATE2:** don't anybody knows how to bind rich:dataTable?

**Part of code:**

```
<p:dataTable 
  id="tableDetail"
  value="#{myBdeCheck.dataListBde}"
  binding="#{myBdeCheck.dataTable}"
  var="bdeItem">

  <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Select" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myBdeCheck.selectedRow}"/>
  </p:column>

  <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="Shift" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.dayShift}"/>
  </p:column>

  <f:facet name="footer">  
    <h:commandButton id="btnAdd" action="#{myBdeCheck.add}"/>
  </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Did I forgot something?

Comment: Is the missing closing tag for `<h:panelGroup>` in the footer a typo?

Comment: No no, I tried to make it shorter to be more synoptic. But thanks

Comment: Ok, but you know that only one direct child element for `f:facet` is allowed (Use a wrapping panelGroup if you have more than one)?.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly do you mean....? In my code is commandbutton framed by h:panelGroup. But I found the problem now - is in binding htmldatatable. If i remove it, the table shows columns normally. So i'm gonna edit my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused by binding (as you suggested yourself). You have to bind `p:dataTable` to

```
org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable
```

instead of `javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable`

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! And don't you know the binding for richfaces?

Comment: Good to hear. I don't use Richfaces, but you can start searching here: http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/trunk/

Comment: Nice which works perfectly... setting `scope` will be the main problem for all.. they may forget it sometime..like me..